# Blurry fonts in Intellij on macOS external screen

Tags: fonts, macos-catalina, intellij-idea

I work on MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017) with macOS Catalina (10.15.7). I work in GoLand (that is IntelliJ option).

After an update came (and I applied it unfortunately) fonts in IDE became stretched when I open it on an external screen.

I tried to turn change fonts smoothing for IntelliJ but this didn't help.

```
~ defaults write  com.jetbrains.intellij AppleFontSmoothing -int 2
~ defaults write  com.jetbrains.intellij CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -int 0
~ defaults read com.jetbrains.intellij
{
    AppleFontSmoothing = 2;
    CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled = 0;
}
```

I use `JetBrains Mono` font that looks great on a laptop screen but is stretched and not smoothed on external screen.

Is there any idea how to fix it?

[image: external monitor screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at this? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016827360-Reporting-font-rendering-problems

JetBrains recommend

```
defaults delete AppleFontSmoothing
defaults delete CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled
defaults delete com.jetbrains.intellij AppleFontSmoothing
defaults delete com.jetbrains.intellij CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled
```

And to experiment with the setting `Use font smoothing when available` in `General` preferences.